# Calculating the proportions of Yes or No responses in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, categorical-data

I am new to R and really trying to wrap my head around everything (even taking online course--which so far has not helped at all).

What I started with is a large data frame containing 97 variables pertaining to compliance with regulations.

I have created multiple dataframes based on the various geographic locations (there is probably an easier way to do it).

In each of these dataframes, I have 7 variables I would like to find the mean of "Yes" and "No" responses.

I first tried:

```
    summary(urban$vio_bag)
   Length     Class      Mode 
      398 character character
```

However, this just tells me nothing useful except that I have 398 responses.

So I put this into a table:

```
urbanbag<-table(urban$vio_bag)
```

This at least provided me with the number of Yes and No responses

```
 Var1  Freq
1 No   365
2 Yes  30
```

So I then converted to a data.frame:

```
urbanbag = as.data.frame(urbanbag)
```

Then viewed it:

```
 summary(urbanbag)

     Var1        Freq      
 No :1   Min.   : 30.0  
 Yes:1   1st Qu.:113.8  
         Median :197.5  
         Mean   :197.5  
         3rd Qu.:281.2  
         Max.   :365.0
```

And the output still definitely did not help.. much more useless actually.
I am not building these Matrices in R. It is a table imported from excel.

I am just so lost and frustrated having spent days trying to figure out something that seems so elementary and googling help which did not work out.

Is there a way to actually do this?

Comment: You can do `prop.table(table(urban$vio_bag))`

Comment: That does work, but will I be able to plot it?

Comment: Yes, we can plot it, use barplot(prop.table(table(urban$vio_bag)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `prop.table` to get the proportion

```
v1 <- prop.table(table(urban$vio_bag))
```

then use `barplot` to plot it

```
barplot(v1)
```

Comment: This is perfect! You are a legend!

Comment: Now lets say I want to compare multiple prop-tables in one barplot.  Say v1, v2, v3. Is that possible?

Comment: @ChrisBova  It would have been better if you provided an example.  Perhaps this works `barplot(sapply(df1, function(x) prop.table(table(x))), legend = TRUE)`

Comment: What I mean is as follows:  Say I would like to compare the compliance between 3 different locations: barplot(kznperm, ecperm, wcperm) did not work. kznperm etc. is the name given to the prop table. The tables come from different dataframes

Comment: @ChrisBova  You can try the code I showed earlier. i.e. `set.seed(24);
 df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:3, function(x) sample(c("Yes", "No"),  100, replace=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
 names(df1) <- paste0("V", 1:3); barplot(sapply(df1, function(x) prop.table(table(x))), legend = TRUE)`

Comment: what do I replace x with? Should I not have separated the locations into different df?

Comment: @ChrisBova  Here the `x` is anonymous function call.  You don't need to replace it.  If you dataset object name is different ie. 'dat', then replace `df1` with `dat`.  Also, if you have many different columns and want to subset only 3 columns then `sapply(df1[locationcolumns], ..`

Comment: in the original dataframe, I have a vector that includes several locations (EC, WC, KZN).  There are 96 other variables, 7 of them are "Yes" or "No" responses to various regulations (vio_perm, vio_size, vio_bag, vio_area, vio_seas, vio_sell, vio_bait).  What I would like to do graphically, is to display each vio for each location.  So there should be 3 bars per graph or 21 bars per graph (3 for each regulation). I couldn't get the last code you gave me to do this.

Comment: @ChrisBova Suppose you want to plot these 7 variables i.e. `nm1 <- c("vio_perm", "vio_size", "vio_bag", "vio_area", "vio_seas", "vio_sell", "vio_bait")` and suppose your object name is `df1`, then `barplot(sapply(df1[nm1], function(x) prop.table(table(x))), legend = TRUE)`

Comment: I get this: <barplot(sapply(data[nm1], function(x) prop.table(table(x))), legend = TRUE)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, nm1) : undefined columns selected>

Comment: @ChrisBova  You should check whether the nm1 elements are the column names or not.  check your column names for any leading/lagging spaces i.e. `colnames(data)`

Comment: colnames(data) did indeed return an error so I renamed the colname to match and the bar plot did return a bar for each vio with ratio of yes/no. How would I do this for each individual location? ie colname = "province" and the three provinces are EC, WC and KZN? same data, just categorized

Comment: For instance say I need to include those three locations separately but on the same graph. Y-axis would have Ratio yes/no and x axis would have "vio_bait" for each location

Comment: @ChrisBova  Could you please post as a new question with a reproducible example as this is not clear from the comments.

Comment: New question posted as: "Creating a bar plot of several variables with different data frames?"

Answer (score 1):

Try with dplyr's `n()` (perfomrs counts) within `sumarisse()`

library(dplyr)

`data %>%  group_by(yes_no_column) %>% summarise(my_counts = n())`

This will give you the counts you're looking for. Adjust the group_by() variables as needed -multiple variables can be used at the time for grouping purposes. Just like with `n()`, a function such as `mean` and `sd` can be passed to `summarise`. If you want to make a column out of each calculated metric, use `mutate()`

Oscar.

Answer (score 1):

prop.table is a useful way of doing this. You can also solve this using mean:

```
mean(urban$vio_bag == "Yes")    
mean(urban$vio_bag == "No")
```